# Application in ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta running on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7

i have problems runnning an mvc2beta application in iis 7.5.

**WebServer**:
Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)

**Application**:
MVC 2 Beta (developted in Visual Studio 2010 Beta)

On IIS i added a new application beneath the Default Web Site and the new application has Application Pool ASP.NET V4.0

If i runn application within Visual Studio everything is fine. but on IIS Server i became an error page:

Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

What is missing?

In Event Log got this Message:

> Application pool 'DefPool' is being
>   automatically disabled due to a series
>   of failures in the process(es) serving
>   that application pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to .NET v4 then delete any older versions from `%windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework` and try again. Also, check again that the application pool isn't set to use v4.0, and not v2.0.

Without seeing your debug messages, it's hard to diagnose what these failures were.

Comment: The problom ist there are no debug information just the messages i posted.